# Chrome extension - working when accessed as HTML file, but not as extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am making an extension for chrome, however this is my first time doing that and so I made a simple script to see if I was doing it correctly.

This script works fine when view as a regular page in the browser, but when it is loaded as a chrome extension it falls down completely. Could someone tell me what special thing has to be changed to allow this to work as an extension?

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src='lib/jquery-1.11.0.min.js'></script>
        <script src='lib/jquery.knob.js'></script>
        <script src='script.js'></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type='text' value='0' class='dial' id='dis'>
        <input type='text' id='in' placeholder='Enter percent to change to'>
        <button onclick="change()">Change it!</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
$(function() {
    $("#dis").knob({
        'readOnly':true
    });
});
function change(){
    var num = document.getElementById('in').value;
    $('#dis').val(num).trigger('change');
};
```

[Zip containing extension and source files.](http://mitchell.elementfx.com/ctest/chrome.zip)

[Online working version (couldn't get it working on JsFiddle or JsBin)](http://mitchell.elementfx.com/ctest/popup.html)

Comment: Could you also post some code samples here, describe your project's structure, explain what it is supposed to do, and perhaps share your hypothesis about what is causing your present problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please carefully read the documentation on Chrome's [Content Security Policy](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy).

Your problem is in using `onclick` attribute. It counts as inline code. You need to get rid of it.

HTML:

```
<button id="button">Change it!</button>
```

Script:

```
$(function() {
    $("#button").click(change);
    $("#dis").knob({
        'readOnly':true
    });
});
```